# Spring @Cacheable ignored for creating proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, proxy

I have some problem with Spring @Cacheable annotation. It is ignored for creating a proxy for cache management.

My situation is next...

My team uses *Spring Boot (2.0)* for our applications.
For some services, we use a cache with *Ehcache 3*.
The structure of *Maven* modules is next:

```
/
+- cache-lib
|
+- service-lib // depend on cache-lib
|
+- app-module // depend on service-lib
```

**cache-lib** is a module which has config class for common configuration of the cache:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomCacheProperties.class)
public class CommonCacheConfig implements JCacheManagerCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    private CustomCacheProperties cacheProperties;

    @Override
    public void customize(javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager) {
        addCachesFromConfiguration(cacheManager, cacheProperties);
    }
    ...
}
```

In **service-lib** there is a service which uses repository object for querying to the database.

```
@Slf4j
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {

    private final DataRepository dataRepository;

    public DataServiceImpl(DataRepository dataRepository) {
        this.dataRepository = dataRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable("DATA_CACHE")
    public Data getData() {
        log.info("Reloading data...");
        return dataRepository.getData();
    }
}
```

Configuration for it:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Data.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = DataRepository.class)
@Import(CommonCacheConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:cache/data-service-cache.properties")
public class DataServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataService dataService(DataRepository dataRepository) {
        return new DataServiceImpl(timeShiftRepository);
    }
}
```

According to [this page](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring) for a class which has *@Cacheable* annotation proxy should be created (as in case of *@Transactional*). However, when I debug *DataService* in **app-module** I can't find any proxy. Spring manages this bean as POJO. And when I use *DataService* anywhere in application it calls repository every time I use it. For example:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(DataServiceConfig.class)
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("Data: {}", dataService.getData());
        log.info("Data: {}", dataService.getData());
    }
}
```

The output for this is:

```
...
2018-06-20 12:47:13.054  INFO 9805 --- [main] org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager      : Cache 'DATA_CACHE' created in Eh107InternalCacheManager.
...
2018-06-20 12:47:24.299  INFO 9805 --- [main] com.example.service.DataServiceImpl  : Reloading data...
2018-06-20 12:47:24.300  INFO 9805 --- [main] com.example.App                      : Data: {...}
2018-06-20 12:47:24.302  INFO 9805 --- [main] com.example.service.DataServiceImpl  : Reloading data...
2018-06-20 12:47:24.303  INFO 9805 --- [main] com.example.App                      : Data: {...}
```

What am I missing?
I guess I should miss something during bean loading, but I don't know what should I look for.

Can anybody give me any suggestion?

Thank you for your time.